# spring dataSource config. with annotaions

Tags: spring, jdbc, annotations, datasource

my dao implementaion;

```
\\here are imports...
@Repository
public class CompanyDaoImp extends JdbcDaoSupport implements CompanyDao {


private static final String INSERTCOMPANY = "INSERT INTO b_company"
        + "(NAME)VALUES(?)";
```

this is my bean;

```
<?xml version=".........

 <!-- TODO add the component-scan and annotation-config elements -->

 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.some.company"/>



 <bean id="companyAppDataSource"   
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/companyapp"/>
 <property name="username" value="root"/>
 <property name="password" value="root"/>
 </bean>
 </beans>
```

i couldn't understand why i keep taking the exception;
.......Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is required.........

Answer (score 0):

`JdbcDaoSupport` doesn't have any annotation to automatically inject the `DataSource`. You have to override the `setDataSource` method like this:

```
<bean name="companyDaoImp" class="...CompanyDaoImp">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="companyAppDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Spring couldn't inject automatically the `DataSource` because you may have multiple data sources and in that case it would be necessary to tell Spring which one you need.

Comment: i think setDataSource is final so i can not override it. The second sol. works but is there any way to make this with just annotaions (except datasource bean)

Comment: @cek You're right. I didn't notice. I removed this in the answer. Sorry.

Comment: no problem. do you think if i am making mistakes while defining the datasource bean?

Comment: You could define another method name (`setDataSource2`), but that is not very pretty. You could also not use `JdbcDaoSupport` and define your own common class for all DAOs (e.g. `AbstractDaoSupport`) with the proper annotation.

Comment: Below JIRA issue talks about the same issue https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4339